# SendKeys.Send("^V"); does not paste an image but it does paste text

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to set clipboard data and invoke a paste to windows. My data is successfully set into the clipboard but when I perform a

```
SendKeys.Send("^V");
```

with an image in the clipboard, it does not paste the image. When text is in the clipboard, it does successfully paste the text.

When I set the clipboard content to contain an image and then close my application and manually perform a CTRL+V, the image pastes successfully.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Is there another way to invoke a paste?

Many Thanks

Comment: Microsoft had to invent WPF so it could legitimately stop supporting these horrid VB6 functions.  Check the MSDN article for notes on how to change your app.config file to make it more compatible.

Comment: Where does it paste *to*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why but I reproduced the issue using MSPaint, and for some reason, you simply need to use a lower-case `v`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // wait 5 secs
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    // go to MSPaint and wait
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^v");
}
```

Pasting text into Notepad worked with capital `V`